# How to make array of textbox fields in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

I'm using the `form_input` function to make a 2d array of textboxes and pulldowns.

The function produces HTML like this:

```
<input type="box" name= "variable">
```

I need to create 30 rows of 5 textboxes (time, event, supplies, sucess{yes/no}, comment).

My plan was to somehow be able to uniquely identify them all so at a later stage when I `$Post` them to another page it wont get confused as to which textbox is `time1` or which textbox is `time2`.

I'm trying to make this array of texboxes in php so that when I use a `for` loop with (`ISSET`) I can stop when I get to a row that is not completed by the user.

This is my code here but im not too sure if its spot on

```
for ($i =0; $i< 30; $i++)
{
    //time part of event field
    echo form_input ($events['time',$i]), 
    //the event itself
    form_input ($events['event',$i]), 
    //supplies used
    form_input ($events['supplies',$i]),
    //successful?
    form_dropdown ($events['success',$i] $success),
    //comment if necessary
    form_input ($events['time',$i]);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Are those really supposed to be commas in the array index? Did you mean to concatenate with the `.` dot, or pass `$i` to the second param of `form_input()`? That being said, I'm still not very sure what you're actually trying to do. Also, there is no input type "box".

Comment: I want to have a 2d array of textboxes with a column id and a row id?

How would I write that in php?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `column id and a row id`? This code is a complete mess, would you please put some effort into your endeavors before posting - this won't even parse, you have two instances of `time`, commas that don't make sense, etc etc. Should we guess what `$events` contains or are you willing to tell us?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand either but regarding the $_POST object; this is from the CI docs:

> CodeIgniter comes with three helper
>   functions that let you fetch POST,
>   COOKIE or SERVER items. The main
>   advantage of using the provided
>   functions rather than fetching an item
>   directly ($_POST['something']) is that
>   the functions will check to see if the
>   item is set and return false (boolean)
>   if not. This lets you conveniently use
>   data without having to test whether an
>   item exists first. In other words,
>   normally you might do something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> if ( ! isset($_POST['something']))
> {
>     $something = FALSE;
> }
> else
> {
>     $something = $_POST['something'];
> }
> ```
>
> With CodeIgniter's built in functions
>   you can simply do this:
>
> ```
> $something = $this->input->post('something');
> ```